# Amazon SES Notifications (SNS) not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-sns

I am still in the [sandbox of Amazons SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html) trying set a bounce email handler.

I am using the [mailbox simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html) to test a bounce/complaint email.

I have created a SNS topic (and I have subscribed to receive notifications from this topic):
[image]

I have selected this topic to receive bounce email notifications, then I have disabled email notifications:

[image]

However, when I send e-mails to bounce@simulator.amazonses.com from SES I still receive a bounceback e-mail and there aren't updates in the SNS topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The configurations of not receiving "Email Feedback" and sending Bounce emails to SNS Topic were set to my **Domain** example.com.

In my **Verified Emails** I had myself@example.com and I was sending e-mails with it.

It happens that my verified e-mail itself had these configurations too, so when I set them to be like those of my domain, everything started working.

If I had tried to send e-mails with anythingelse@example.com it would've worked.

Answer (score 12):

I will try to make this issue clearer with some screenshots.

It can happen *outside the sandbox* too.

I did not realise that the Amazon SES console can set a SNS bounce/complaint topic for the **domain**, as well as a separate SNS setting for every **verified email address**.

[image]

So each verified email address can have its own different SNS bounce/complaint topic if you want! If you want them all the same, you have to go and set them all up in the console: tell each one to use SNS, otherwise they have 'Email Feedback Forwarding' set to "enabled" and this will override the setting at domain level.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Email Feedback Forwarding](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications-via-email.html#notifications-via-email-disabling) and [SES notifications via Amazon SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications.html) are exposed as two separate mechanisms.  The linked documentation describes as much:

> You must receive bounce and complaint notifications **either by email or
>   through Amazon SNS** – The default method is by email, through a feature
>   called email feedback forwarding.

Since you've shown that Email Feedback Forwarding is disabled, you are likely still receiving bounce notifications via your verified SNS email subscription.

To test, try removing your email subscription from the SNS topic and then sending an email to the bounce simulator again. To test further, you could subscribe a different email address or even an [SQS queue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html) to verify that bounce notifications are still being published.

Comment: I removed my subscription e-mail and I still only receive the bounceback e-mail. I added a SQS to my SNS and when I create a topic myself, I receive an email if I'm subscribed, but then I tried again the bounce test and there isn't any topic in SNS and I still just receive the bounceback email. I must be doing something wrong, but I have no clue.